# Call custom AutoIt function from python

Tags: python, python-2.7, autoit

I found a way to run built in auto it functions from python using the following code

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch
Auto = Dispatch("AutoItX3.Control")
Auto.Run("notepad.exe", "", 5)
```

Is there a similar way to call custom methods i.e methods defined in `my_AutoIt_File.au3`
Say I have a method in this file

```
Func my_autoit_method
   ;some code
EndFunc
```

Is there a way to call this `my_autoit_method` from python?

Comment: Maybe the documentation of `AutoItX3.Control` can tell you that.

Answer (score 1):

From the help file:

**AutoIt specific command Line Switches**

- Form1: AutoIt3.exe [/ErrorStdOut] [/AutoIt3ExecuteScript] file
  [params ...]

  ```
             Execute an AutoIt3 Script File
  ```

*/ErrorStdOut*    Allows to redirect fatal error to StdOut which can be    captured by an application as Scite editor. This switch can be used    with a compiled script.

To execute a standard AutoIt Script File 'myscript.au3', use the command:
'AutoIt3.exe myscript.au3'

- Form2: Compiled.exe [/ErrorStdOut] [params ...]

  ```
          Execute an compiled AutoIt3 Script File produced with Aut2Exe.
  ```
- Form3: Compiled.exe [/ErrorStdOut] [/AutoIt3ExecuteScript file]
  [params ...]

  ```
          Execute another script file from a compiled AutoIt3 Script File. Then you don't need to fileinstall another copy of AutoIT3.exe in your compiled file.
  ```
- Form4: AutoIt3.exe [/ErrorStdOut] /AutoIt3ExecuteLine "command line"

  ```
          Execute one line of code.
  ```

To execute a single line of code, use the command:

```
Run(@AutoItExe & ' /AutoIt3ExecuteLine  "MsgBox(0, ''Hello World!'', ''Hi!'')"')
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to expose your AutoIt Function to other applications. This could be done easily with [AutoItObject](https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/110379-autoitobject-udf/), which can [register an object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/com/registering-objects-in-the-rot) in the ROT.

The AutoIt Code would be:

```
#include <AutoItObject.au3>

$oObject = _AutoItObject_Create()
_AutoItObject_RegisterObject($oObject, 'MyVery.CustomApplication')
_AutoItObject_AddMethod($oObject, '_my_custom_function', '_my_custom_function')

While Sleep(100)
WEnd

Func _my_custom_function($oSelf)
    MsgBox(0, '', 'AutoIt says Hi')
    Exit
EndFunc
```

The Python Code should be:

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch
Auto = Dispatch("MyVery.CustomApplication")
Auto._my_custom_function()
```